# Ubuntu 16.04 guest cannot connect internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I know this kind of problem was asked many times, but I can't really find a solution for my problem and have no clue where to go.

I'm using Oracle virtualbox, and here is my environment.

- Guest: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Host: Windows 10

This is the network setting for Ubuntu. **I do need to access Ubuntu from Windows**, so I set the Bridge Adapter.
[image]
Here is the setting for /etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I tried to take a screenshot of "Edit Connection" dialog but it gives me a black image and didn't work. So I list up the info below,

Ethernet tab

- Device  [eth0]
- Cloned Mac address [blank]
- MTU [automatic]
- Wake on LAN [Default]

Comment: The default NAT mode should work. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: Thanks, yes it does work with NAT mode, but I need to access the Ubuntu via ip address since it has a web server on it. Do I need to set up port forwarding for it?

Comment: Oh wow, I tried some port forwarding setting then it just works.

Comment: Yes, that's it. With bridged mode you would need a dedicated network device.

Comment: The bridge adapter used to work for a long time, but it suddenly stopped working for some reason. Anyway thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GabrielaGarcia suggested to change the NAT mode, so I switched to "NAT" then set port forwarding at "Port Forwarding" in "Advanced" pane like the following.

```
Name    Protocol Host IP      Host Port  Guest IP   Guest Port
Rule1   TCP      192.168.56.1 80         10.0.2.15  3000
```

Now I can access the web server on the Ubuntu guest from the Window host by typing "http://192.168.56.1".